# Pulling xml data in Flash with a button

Tags: xml, flash

I have been failing to do a thing with Flash actionscript2.0; Here is the problem-

My xml file name is: sea.xml
On my fla file, there is a button named: do; and a movieClip named: loader;

What I am trying to do is- load xml only when the button is pressed. So I tried this-

```
myXML:XML = new XML;

do.onRelease = function(){
myXML.load("sea.xml");
}

myXML.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
loadMovie(myXML.firstChild.childNodes[00.firstChild.nodeValue, loader);
}
```

BUT it's not working. How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

```
myXML:XML = new XML;

do.onRelease = function(){
myXML.load("sea.xml");
}

myXML.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
trace(myXML.toString());
}
```

and post here the output please.